# SQL2014 stored procedure - getting errors on code that literally worked yesterday

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I have a proc designed to move data from a linked sql2008r2 server with several identical dbs to my new sql2014 server. It creates all new databases and objects and transforms/treats the data on import. You run it on a source database name and it does the rest.  I've used it for a couple of months without problems, including as recently as last night.

Part of the code selects before and after record counts for each table for a report at the end.

Today, the before/after counts are preventing me from running the stored procedure or altering it. (multiple errors, since it does this after each table.)

Here are the lines it freaks out about.  Maybe there's a better way to do this than using a temp table?

```
exec('select count(*) as beforerecs into ##t from [sourceserver\localities].' + @dbname + '.dbo.' + @Tabname + ';')
select @sCount=beforerecs from ##t  --line 96
drop table ##t
exec('select count(*) as afterrecs into ##t from ' + @destdbname + '.dbo.' + @Tabname + ';')
select @dcount=afterrecs from ##t   --line 99
drop table ##t
```

The errors I'm getting are complaining because the table and column don't technically  exist until the previous line of code is executed, but it didn't care about that until today:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure MigrateLocalityDB, Line 96
>   Invalid column name 'beforerecs'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure MigrateLocalityDB, Line 99
>   Invalid column name 'afterrecs'.

This was the only way I could think of at the time to get the record counts using my database and table name variables.  Suggestions for a better way are most welcome!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Global temporary tables are visible to any user and any connection after they are created, and are deleted when all users that are referencing the table disconnect from the instance of SQL Server. Are you shure that somebody else or other query changed the table? Have you closed your session on SQL Server from the last time you ran this script?

Comment: Yes, both the server and the client I've been using have been rebooted recently and nobody else has done any modifications.

Comment: I just tried commenting out the line 96 and line 99 instances that refer to the column created in the temp tables, and the errors stop.  Of course, that doesn't solve the problem but shows that the temp tables are not the cause.

Comment: Maybe some other ##t tables were happening on the server, because changing ##t to #t resolved the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: How can I close this question and credit you with the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Balde actually answered this, but I'm not sure how to close the question without an answer post.

The problem turned out to be related to using global temp tables with a name that is sometimes used in other stored procedures (##t) --something that hadn't been a problem before, but was lazy on my part.  Changing them to local temporary tables (#t) allowed me to compile (alter) the proc, but the proc failed to run as the results weren't available to the subsequent query.  The solution was to continue using global temp tables but simply make the name more unique to prevent conflicts (##tlocmig). Live and learn.

Thanks to Balde for getting me on the right track!